# jQuery add class at intervals

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class at intervals through a list. This class will be a css animation that will bring each list item onto the page so the effect will be a wave of items animating in. A looping delay  addClass function would be perfect but is this even possible?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    ul li {
      -webkit-animation: animation .5s ease-out;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animation {
        from { -webkit-transform: 
            translate(-500px); }
        to { -webkit-transform: 
            translate(0px); }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

or CodePen:
http://cdpn.io/aAxHp

thanks to anyone who can help me out on this

Comment: interval of time, I assume ?

Comment: sure - short time intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: added a clearInterval when all the items have animated in, or it'll sit there running forever

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    ul li{
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-500px);
    }
    ul li.animate {
      -webkit-animation: animation .5s ease-out;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animation {
        from { -webkit-transform: 
            translate(-500px); }
        to { -webkit-transform: 
            translate(0px); }
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if($('li:not(.animate)').size() == 0){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }else{
      $('li:not(.animate)').first().addClass('animate');
    }
  }, 400);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks to all who replied so promptly. Well done koosa, that's perfect - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `setInterval` function, here is an example of how it is used : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XZN8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `class` in an interval use `setInterval`

```
var time = 1000;

setInterval(function(){
  $('ul').find('li') //or loop through 'li' depends on what you want to select
         .addClass('some-class')
},time);
```

where `1000` is `1`second